# Special file in UNIX file system when mounting?

Tags: file, unix, operating-system, filesystems, mount

I am reading `The UNIX Time-Sharing System` by D. M. Ritchie and K. Thompson, where they briefly introduce the UNIX OS. In the file system section, when they talk about the "mount", they say the following 2 paragraphs. And I have a few questions about the bold and itatic content in the paragraphs.

> Paragraph 1: When an I/O request is made to a file whose i-node
>   indicates that it is special, the last 12 device address words are
>   immaterial, and the first specifies an internal device name, which is
>   interpreted as a pair of numbers representing, respectively, a
>   ***device type*** and ***subdevice number***. The device type indicates which system routine will deal with I/O on that device; the
>   subdevice number selects, for example, a disk drive attached to a
>   particular controller or one of several similar terminal interfaces.
>
> Paragraph 2: In this environment, the implementation of the mount
>   system call (Section 3.4) is quite straightforward. mount maintains a
>   ***system table*** whose argument is the i-number and ***device name of the ordinary file*** specified during the mount, and whose
>   ***corresponding value*** is the device name of the indicated special file. This table is searched for each i-number/device pair that turns
>   up while a path name is being scanned during an open or create; if a
>   match is found, ***the i-number is replaced by the i-number of the
>   root directory and the device name is replaced by the table value.***

1. From the first paragraph, I know that ***device name*** is something existing in a ***special file's*** i-node. However, why in the second paragraph it says the ***ordinary file*** also has it?
2. What is the ***system table*** the `mount` tries to maintain? In para. 2 is it indicating that the system table is part of the internal file system, and the mount process makes such a table that the entries of it are ***special files*** that point to files in the mounted external device?

Comment: Better to ask here. https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with 2 observations:

1. `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2` takes a *special file* `/dev/sda2`, and a non-special file (*ordinary file*) `/mnt/sda2`.
2. file name lookup has to know how to cross into another mounted filesystems.

Let's assume that `/dev/sda1` is device 100, and mounted on `/`. Let's assume that `/dev/sda2` is device 200, and mounted on `/mnt/sda2`. What happens when you look up `/mnt/sda2/x`? That file is stored as `/x` on `/dev/sda2`. Here's what happens:

1. Assume that the inode number of the root inode is 1 on every filesystem.
2. The OS looks up `mnt` in inode 1 of device 100, and finds e.g. inode 5.
3. The OS checks it's global system table of mounts to see if (device 100, inode 5) maps to something - it doesn't.
4. The OS looks up `sda2` in inode 5 of device 100, and finds e.g. inode 17.
5. The OS checks it's global system table of mounts to see if (device 100, inode 17) maps to something.
6. Because `/dev/sda2` is mounted onto `/mnt/sda2`, the table returns `/dev/sda2`, which is device 200 - we're crossing into another mounted filesystem.
7. The OS lookups up `x` in inode 1 of device 200, and finds e.g. inode 11.
8. Lookup returns (device 200, inode 5).

So to answer your questions:

1. The ordinary file is the mount point. "Ordinary" means "not a special file". Note that it is possible to mount a regular file, not just a directory. Docker uses this capability.
2. The system table's entries are *mount points* which point to mounted devices.